# How to remove pictures located at specific position(eg. top-right cornor) from every PPT slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint, shapes

I have many powerpoint files which have a picture at the top-right corner on every single slide.  It is neither a master slide, NOT a custom layout shape.

They were pasted one by one to all slides.

I have some codes as below to remove all shapes(pictures) from slides, but how to locate the shapes(pictures) at a specific location of a slide?

---

```
 For Each Slide In SlideList

    Set sldTemp = ActivePresentation.Slides(Slide)
    For lngCount = sldTemp.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
        With sldTemp.Shapes(lngCount)

         '----------Delete All shapes = picture---------- 
            If .Type = msoPicture Then
                .Delete
            End If
        End With
    Next
Next
```

'-----------------------------------------

I am not very good at VBA for powerpoint coding, any suggestion is appreciated.
thank you.

Comment: The pictures need to be removed are same. I've try Google & Bing a lot, and found the solution to remove picture by its name. But the picture's name could be randomly in different powerpoint files.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the position by looking at the Top and Left properties.  You could also check the size if they're all the same size.

Eg:

```
 If .Type = msoPicture Then
     If .Top > x and .Top < y and .Left > a and .Left < b Then 
       .Delete
       Exit For
     End If
 End If
```

Where x,y, a and b are variables or hard-coded values.

Comment: OK i will try on 2 pixel definition  displays and feedback

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Tim Williams very much.

The pilot codes run correctly on 3 Win10 x86 computers.

by the way, according to this saying

*By default, the size of the new presentation in PowerPoint, is currently a widescreen type presentation, 13.333 inch by 7.5 inch. Mostly you will have 96 dots per inch (dpi) on your screen settings, so this means that a default PowerPoint presentation has a resolution of 1280 by 720 pixels.*

though the top-left values set below can match exactly the top-right small logo(shape) in my powerpoint slide, and the same results from 3 different display ,and one of which is in low definition mode.

Sub DeleteAllTopRightShapes()

```
Dim sldTemp As Slide
Dim lngTemp As Long
Dim lngCount As Long

For Each sldTemp In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For lngCount = sldTemp.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
        With sldTemp.Shapes(lngCount)



        If .Type = msoPicture Then
          If .Top >= 0 And .Top < 60 And .Left >= 400 Then

            .Delete

          End If
        End If

        End With
    Next
Next
    MsgBox "Process complete!"
```

End Sub

Comment: PowerPoint doesn't use pixels as dimensions, it uses points (72 points per inch). For your purposes, pixels are totally irrelevant.